# Retrieving Records and Saving to a Database in a single C# Web Service

Tags: c#, json, azure, get

Hi i am trying to combine a C# webservice in azure with a get and a post at the same time, the idea is to get the details of a CD by the uniqueCDcode and the webservice outputs just the json information AND the uniqueCDcode needs to be stored in a different table CDClicked to i get a list of all the clickedCD's so i am able to take the last 50 as for trending etc. but don't really seem to get it to work. This is what i have so far

```
    //// WS# 00002 GET THE ALBUM DETAILS
    [Route("api/Music/Album/{uniqueCDcode}")]
    public HttpResponseMessage GetAlbum(int uniqueCDcode)
    {
        return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
            new { AlbumMusic = db.Music
                .Where(am => am.uniqueCDcode == uniqueCDcode);

        db.CDClicked.Add(uniqueCDcode);

    }
```

Comment: What is would like to do is when the user clicks the button for more details of the CD in the website, the webservice returns that information from the database (the top part that works fine) AND the webservice also stores inside a different table of the DB what CD the user has clicked (the uniqueCDcode)

Comment: You need to retrieve you record, do the save, then return the response. The Add() method call, second part, isn't working because the return statement is returning a value and then stopping the execution of your service. Your logic needs to be done before the return statement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to retrieve your record/do the save, *then* return the response. The Add() method call to dbContext (second part) isn't working because the return statement is returning a value first, and then stopping the execution of your service, so it never gets to the second part. Your logic needs to be done before the return statement.

For example:

```
[Route("api/Music/Album/{uniqueCDcode}")]
public HttpResponseMessage GetAlbum(int uniqueCDcode)
{
    db.CDClicked.Add(uniqueCDcode);

    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, 
        new { AlbumMusic = db.Music
            .Where(am => am.uniqueCDcode == uniqueCDcode )});
}
```

You also had some formatting issues in the code.  Your braces and parens didn't match up (at least in the code that you pasted into SO.)  I corrected in my answer below.

***Note: I can't test the code at the moment due to hurricane-related issues, but this is the general concept to get you going again.***

Comment: thank you so much for your answer, if i would like to store the date and time in a seperate colomn as well what do i need to add? to the db.CDClicked.Add(uniqueCDcode); i forgot to add that to the original question.

Comment: Wow....  That is a whole other new question entirely.  If I assume you're using Entity Framework: You need to add the column to your database/model, then create an instance of that model and pass that to your add method instead of just the uniqueCDcode.  Or you can add a column to your database that stores the datetime value by default, then you don't need to modify your C# code at all. Are you using Entity Framework and if so, are you going Entity-First, Code-First, or Database-First?

Comment: thanks actually your idea "add a column to your database that stored the datetime value by default" works perfectly fine. I used the default timestamp function.

Comment: sorry, i think i accidentally clicked it, it's working fine :-)